# How to deploy React app with Stripe integration

Tags: reactjs, deployment, build, stripe-payments

I have a hard time figuring out how to deploy my React app with simple Stripe integration. I figured out how to run a back-end and front-end simultaniously on my local machine and my test payments are working. After deployment all my front-end is still working correctly, but as soon as I click the "Checkout" button I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` at this url: `http://localhost:5000/create-checkout-session`. Can somebody explain how to make everything work correctly after deployment rather than only in development? You can reach the site here: https://oleh-fake-shop.netlify.app/

My **server.js:**

```
require('dotenv').config()
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.REACT_APP_TEST_KEY);
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: [
      {
        // Provide the exact Price ID (for example, pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
        price: 'price_1KsOTNCPEspXM0sLtOYAeHUR',
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_PORT}?success=true`,
    cancel_url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_PORT}?canceled=true`,
  });
  res.redirect(303, session.url);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => console.log('Running on port 5000'))
```

My **StripeModule.jsx:**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

const ProductDisplay = () => {

  const formRef = useRef()
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    formRef.current.submit()
  }

  return <section>
    <form ref={formRef} action={`http://localhost:5000/create-checkout-session`} method="POST">
      <Button variant="success" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Checkout
      </Button>
    </form>
  </section>
}

const Message = ({message}) => (
  <section>
    <p>{message}</p>
  </section>
)

export default function StripeModule() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check to see if this is a redirect back from Checkout
    const query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)

    if (query.get("success")) {
      setMessage("Order placed! You will receive an email confirmation.")
    }

    if (query.get("canceled")) {
      setMessage(
        "Order canceled -- continue to shop around and checkout when you're ready."
      );
    }
  }, [])

  return message ? (
    <Message message={message}/>
  ) : (
    <ProductDisplay/>
  )
}
```

My **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "fake_shop",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "concurrently": "^7.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "stripe": "^8.219.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"react-scripts start\" \"node server.js\"",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Your remote frontend code is trying to make a request to your backend code by sending a request to `http://localhost:5000`. That URL is a local URL to your development machine and wouldn't work with a remote host unless you deploy your frontend code and backend code on the same netlify instance and configure your requests accordingly. 

To get this resolved, You'd want to deploy your backend code to netlify or heroku and use its remote URL as part of your form's action property. i.e. `action={'https://<example-remote-url>/create-checkout-session'}`

Comment: There are other options as converting your integration to a server-side rendered app but that'd require additional changes.

Comment: @hanzo Thank you for the tip. I managed to properly upload my back-end to heroku and front to Netlify and everything is working now!